# floating left and right using smarty components

Tags: css, smarty

I have the following:

```
{container class="memberhome_hrefs_cont" stylesheet="member_home_links.style"}   

{capture name='username'}
{text %.components.member_home.label_welcome username=$username}  
{text %.components.member_home.label_profileno profileid=$profileid}

{/capture}
{block title=$smarty.capture.username} 

{/container}
```

that gives-me

> Welcome username Member nº: 20

And I would like to set "Welcome username" floating left and "Member nº: 20" floating right.

to achive:

> Welcome username                          [space here]                                                       Member nº: 20

Any help here?

thank you.

Comment: `Smarty` has nothing to do with the request. It is just a matter of `CSS`.

Comment: I already sort this problem out.Thanks.